# Split the column name and values

Tags: r

I have parameter name-value pairs of the following form:

```
[1] "action=purchase"              "itemId=EST-21"
```

How can I construct output with the parameter name as the column name and the values as the column values? For example, I want the above values to be outputted as:

```
[Column names] [1]action    itemId
[Column values][2]purchase  EST-21
```

Comment: Reproducible example is required [as the solution will depend on the form of the input]

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you had your parameter-value pairs stored as strings in a vector:

```
(dat <- c("action=purchase", "itemId=EST-21"))
# [1] "action=purchase" "itemId=EST-21"
```

Then you could split on the equals sign with `strsplit`:

```
(spl <- strsplit(dat, "="))
# [[1]]
# [1] "action"   "purchase"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "itemId" "EST-21"
```

You can then construct a vector with the appropriate values and names with:

```
setNames(sapply(spl, "[", 2), sapply(spl, "[", 1))
#     action     itemId 
# "purchase"   "EST-21"
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert the substring on the lhs of `=`, we can directly use `read.table/read.csv` by specifying the `sep` as `=` and the `header=TRUE`

```
read.table(text=dat, sep="=", header=TRUE, 
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#  action purchase
#1 itemId   EST-21
```

NOTE: 'dat' is taken from @josliber's post.

Comment: Very cool! It took me a while, but I think I've wrapped my head around why this works :)